# LEFT JOIN generating the wrong SUM

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a simple join of two different tables `stock_tracker_max` and `tbl_shipment_data_final`. However, one of the SUMs I get post join is completely wrong.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 

a.Stock_Tracker
,SUM(a.Qty_Invoiced) as Qty_Invoiced
,SUM(a.Qty_Received) as Qty_Received


FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.stock_tracker_max` a

where (a.stock_tracker) ='WK06 GABONA'
group by 1
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT 

b.Stock_Tracker
,SUM(b.Qty_Shipped) as Qty_Shipped


FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_shipment_data_final`  b 

where (b.stock_tracker) ='WK06 GABONA'
group by 1
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT 

a.Stock_Tracker
,b.Stock_Tracker
,SUM(a.Qty_Invoiced) as Qty_Invoiced
,SUM(a.Qty_Received) as Qty_Received
,SUM(b.Qty_Shipped) as Qty_Shipped


FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.stock_tracker_max` a LEFT JOIN (SELECT Stock_Tracker,Sum(Qty_Shipped) as Qty_Shipped from `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_shipment_data_final` group by 1) b 
on a.Stock_Tracker = b.Stock_Tracker 

where (a.stock_tracker) ='WK06 GABONA'
group by 1,2
```

I have simplified the task for the purposes of this exercise (this affects more than just one `Stock_Tracker` but I just filtered to make it simpler to explain). The first two queries in the above are when I query each table separately - I get the right data in both cases.

However, in the third query (in the image above), when I try join the two tables, I get a completely incorrect value for column Qty_Shipped. The second query gives Qty_Shipped as 4338 but when I do the join this jumps up to 78084.

Both the first query and second query generate just one row (with the two having identical values for `Stock_Tracker`).

This is the third query's result:

[image]

I am struggling to understand what's causing the issue here.

Comment: Pictures of code are not particularly helpful. And envisioning your data from just your queries requires more effort from those who'd like to help you. That said, why are you summing the result from your table B, which is already a summation in the subquery?

Comment: Sorry- edited to add code. Ok it's fixed - it seems like me summing again (as you mentioned above) is what's driving the issue. 

Can you explain how summing again gets to such a number? Just to understand what's happening. Keen to understand this as there was only one matching row in each of the first two queries case..

Comment: You are summing all results from the subquery, not just those that match your outer `where` clause. Why do you need a subquery vs. just a join?

Comment: From your output; I suspect `tbl_shipment_data_final` has duplicated data for a 
`Stock_Tracker` in your where condition. Can you please confirm on this; whether `tbl_shipment_data_final` has duplicated data for `stock_tracker ='WK06 GABONA'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each stock_tracker, you are joining every stock_tracker_max row with their tbl_shipment_data_final sum. So, with eighteen stock_tracker_max rows for the stock_tracker in your example, you'll get the shipment sum eighteen times. By aggregating again down to one row for the stock_tracker, the resulting sum is hence eighteen times as big as the original sum.

Instead aggregate both tables per stock_tracker first and then join the results.

```
SELECT
  m.stock_tracker,
  m.sum_qty_invoiced,
  m.sum_qty_received,
  f.sum_qty_shipped
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    stock_tracker,
    SUM(qty_invoiced) AS sum_qty_invoiced,
    SUM(qty_received) AS sum_qty_received
  FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.stock_tracker_max`
  WHERE stock_tracker = 'WK06 GABONA'
  GROUP BY stock_tracker
) m
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    stock_tracker,
    SUM(qty_shipped) AS sum_qty_shipped
  FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_shipment_data_final`
  WHERE stock_tracker = 'WK06 GABONA'
  GROUP BY stock_tracker
) f ON f.stock_tracker = m.stock_tracker
ORDER BY m.stock_tracker;
```

### Explaining your query in detail

Here is why your query does not work. Let's say you have this data:

| stock_tracker | qty_invoiced | qty_received |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WK06 GABONA | 10 | 10 |
| WK06 GABONA | 20 | 20 |

and

| stock_tracker | qty_shipped |
| --- | --- |
| WK06 GABONA | 5 |
| WK06 GABONA | 7 |

Now you aggregate your second table thus:

| stock_tracker | qty_shipped |
| --- | --- |
| WK06 GABONA | 12 |

Then you join this result to the first table:

| stock_tracker | qty_invoiced | qty_received | qty_shipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WK06 GABONA | 10 | 10 | 12 |
| WK06 GABONA | 20 | 20 | 12 |

Now you aggregate again and build the final sums:

| stock_tracker | qty_invoiced | qty_received | qty_shipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WK06 GABONA | 30 | 30 | 24 |

You have multiplied the second table's sum by the number of matching rows in the first table.

Comment: I fully understand why yours work and is more logical (to aggregate each first) but I still don't really get why mine generates the wrong result. 

My Query 1 generates just one row for this particular stock_tracker in question - so shouldn't this be the case in Query 3 also? If I look at Query 3, to me it looks like there would be just one row for each stock tracker (given the group by aggregation), and hence the join should happen once (and not 18 times)? Just trying to understand where I am wrong in this interpretation.

Comment: I've added an explanation with simple sample data to my answer, so you can understand the issue. You can check this yourself by not aggregating your main query, but looking at the joined rows instead.

Comment: I think what confused me here is the order of operations. I was looking at it starting from SELECT but strictly speaking the join happens first and only then does the second aggregation happen. Either way, I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in Query 3 every string from `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.stock_tracker_max` joins with string with sum(Qty_Shipped) from `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_shipment_data_final`.
78084/4338=18, so you have 18 * sum, but if i understand correctly you need sum of 18 values. Correct query is

```
SELECT 
a.Stock_Tracker
,b.Stock_Tracker
,SUM(a.Qty_Invoiced) as Qty_Invoiced
,SUM(a.Qty_Received) as Qty_Received
,SUM(b.Qty_Shipped) as Qty_Shipped
FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.stock_tracker_max` a 
LEFT JOIN `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_shipment_data_final` b
on a.Stock_Tracker = b.Stock_Tracker 
where (a.stock_tracker) ='WK06 GABONA'
group by 1,2
```

Comment: No. If the stock_tracker has 5 A rows and 4 B rows for instance, you'll create 5 x 4 = 20 rows which you then aggregate, thus multiplying the A sums by 4 and the B sum by 5.